# Annotation import giving error on clean

Tags: android, eclipse, annotations, android-annotations

I have a weird situation here. My application is using annotation in android. I had to use few of the methods which requires annotated class directly. But when ever I am cleaning my project or starting my eclipse imports is giving me error.

```
 import com.black.devil.app.view.CustomDetailsItemView_ cannot be resolved
```

Have anybody faced this problem before or any clue how to resolve it. Currently, after cleaning my project or starting eclipse, I remove all my imports and then again re import help me resolve my error. But I need to do this every time I clean/ start eclipse. Any permanent solution for this. I don't what code to post so tell if I need to post any thing else.

thanks Black Devil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a well-known issue on Eclipse. We have a [section in the wiki](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/FAQ#wiki-import) for this.

You can fix it by (here is an example for `Pref` but it should work for every generated clases :

- Importing the whole package: import com.company.*;
- Using a fully qualified name : @SharedPref com.company.MyPref_ myPref;
- Having MyBean and MyPref_ in the same package.

Comment: Hey thnx DayS. That worked. But is still there no solution for this apart from import? (as this only can be possibly easiest solution in my case) :D

Comment: The easiest way is to never reference generate classes in your code. However you'll still have this kind of problem for `@SharedPref` because we're forced to use generated class in the code

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the path to your library was correct?
check it in Project->Properties->Java Build Path

Comment: Yup every thing working fine wrt to build path and project working. Problem seems to arise when I clean or restart/start eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

try to mark generated-sources/annotations folder as "Root sources". This works in intellij idea.